# Capistrano install directory problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, directory, capistrano

I'm doing my first Rails deployment and using capistrano, following my host's directions:

I have the domain plantality.com.

I've created the gws folder for my app.

I've installed with capistrano and followed all the wiki instructions I could find.

public_html is pointing to gws/public but capistano has installed my app to gws/current

I've double checked that my deploy.rb paths are correct.

I've created a symlink between gws/public and public_html (I tried one between gws/current/public and public_html but it didn't help.

I'm trying to use Passenger if it makes any difference.

Here is my deploy.rb:

```
set :user, 'plantali'
set :scm_username, 'solent'
set :scm_password, '<removed>'
set :svnserver, 'plantality.sourcerepo.com'
set :application, "gws"
set :repository, "http://#{svnserver}/plantality/gws/gws"
set :server, 'plantality.com'
set :applicationdir, 'gws'
set :use_sudo, false
set :keep_releases, 5
set :scm, :subversion

role :web, "plantality.com" # Your HTTP server, Apache/etc
role :app, "plantality.com" # This may be the same as your `Web` server
role :db, "plantality.com", :primary => true # This is where Rails migrations will run
#role :db, ""

set :deploy_to, "/home/#{user}/#{applicationdir}"
set :group_writeable, false
```

Comment: Note that you don't need the `:applicationdir` directive in your example above. The Capistrano convention is to just use `:application` because the assumption is that the application directory name will be the same as the application name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capistrano deploys releases into timestamped directories under the `releases` directory and creates a symbolic link named `current` that points to the root of the Rails application within the latest release directory.†

Therefore the Rails root of your application is `/home/<user>/gws/current/` and Passenger needs to be configured to serve the application from there accordingly. Set the Apache `DocumentRoot` in the virtual host that Passenger is using to `/home/<user>/gws/current/public` and restart Passenger.

† Incidentally, this is how Capistrano can easily roll back a bad release—it simply recreates the symlink to point to the previous timestamped release.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to do this with a puppet then capistrano situation. I want puppet to set up the vhost to point to ..../current/public , but that doesn't exist until cap deploys, which gives puppet fits. any ideas?